# Codeigniter template library and HMVC ( mx library ) the static method run()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

i have this testing code which am working with ..
i have a module called `ms` and and another one called `test`
the `test` controller code is :

```
<?php
class Test extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->template->title($this->config->item('site_name','app'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->template->build('index');
    }
}
```

and the code inside `ms` is :

```
<?php
//ms module
class Msrofi extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->template->title($this->config->item('site_name','app'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $t = Modules::run('test/test/index');
        var_dump($t);
        $this->template->build('index_message');
    }
}
```

the problem is that the build function inside `test` is trying to find the `index` view file inside the `ms` views folder not the `test` views folder ..
i checked the `$this->_module` and it gave me the `ms` module name ..
any one know how to fix that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `test` module is being called in the context of the `ms` one, `$this->template->build()` is looking for a view file in the `ms` module. The same way you can load models and libraries cross-module, you would have to do this for your view path as well:

```
class Test extends MX_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // This path works only from the "test" module
        // $this->template->build('index');

        // This path works from any module
        $this->template->build('test/index');
    }
}
```

It's a little annoying maybe to have to explicitly call the module path in the module itself, but cross-module dependency defeat some of the goals of modularity in the first place.

A quick aside: `Modules::run()` output not returned, but directly echoed, so you can't assign it to a variable or `print_r`/`var_dump` it without using an output buffer:

```
ob_start();
Modules::run('test/test/index');
$t = ob_get_clean();
var_dump($t);
```

Comment: that's worked but the result of the out put of `var_dupm($t)` was `string '' (length=0)`, even though in the log it load the view as you mentioned .. but if i used `$this->load->view()` it will out put the content of the view file..

Comment: I previously removed the part of my answer that talked about that, I just edited it back in, but I'm not sure I completely understand what problem you're still having.

Comment: even if i did just output the data of the test/index view directly using the `Modules::run` it will out put nothing .. and your code also output is `string '' (length=0)` .. and yes you do understand my problem .. its that the build function output nothing from the `test` module , and just a note when ur using the template library the output of the `Moudles::run` can be assigned to a var and it will not output the data directly to the page

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the module.php the run method

The following example is I have to use the fix solution：

1. Open the third_party/MX/Modules.php
2. Near 75 lines to find

   $buffer = ob_get_clean();
3. Increase in its following：

   if($output === NULL && $buffer === ''){
   $output = CI::$APP->output->get_output();
   }

At this time, it should be able to work properly...